# Update Multiple Items in DynamoDB without exceeding Maximum Throughput

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, throughput, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm trying to perform `update_item` to my DynamoDB for each entry in a list. In the list the columns are `id` and `total_sales` where the total sales updates every hour. The idea is to parse the list and update each item (associated with the id in the list) and update the `total_sales` value but there are more than 5000 entries in the list and it exceeded my maximum throughput. Is there a more efficient way than simply doing this

```py
def write_to_dynamo(id, total_sales):
    response = table.update_item(
            Key={
                'id': id
            },
            UpdateExpression="set stats.revenue = :r",
            ExpressionAttributeValues={
                ':r': total_sales
            },
            ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
        return response

def main():
    for item in lst:
        write_to_dynamo(item.id, item.total_sales)
```

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB itself - **no**.

If you want to use `UpdateItem`, you need to make individual API calls.

If you want to **replace** an item, there is `BatchWriteItem`, which bundles requests, but even that consumes the same throughput.

You could write your changes to an SQS queue and then have a Lambda Function respond to that Queue and update items. This setup takes care of the retries when you exceed the throughput and can make your setup more resilient, but it will still consume the same throughput.

Comment: I mean would there be a more efficient solution than just parsing the entire list and sending 5k `UpdateItem` requests ?

Comment: If you need to update 5k records you need to do 5k UpdateItem calls. I outlined a potential architecture improvement already. If you're throughput limited, parallelization won't help you as well.